# Did Grothendieck and Hörmander ever meet?

Tags: ho.history-overview

I carelessly announced a seminar talk **Grothendieck meets Hörmander** in which I try to explain that Grothendieck's early work in functional analysis could have had a bigger influence on Hörmander's study of partial differential operators than it actually had.

The obvious question following from the title is: **Did they ever meet personally?**

As both received the Fields medal in the 1960s a personal meeting at some ICM would have been plausible. However, Grothendieck is not on the list of speakers of the ICM in Stockholm and did not come to Moscow in 1966. Grothendieck gave a plenary talk at the ICM 1958 in Edinburgh but I did not find out whether Hörmander participated then.

I would be very grateful if someone has some evidence at least for a possible meeting of them.

Comment: I have no definite answer to your question. However, it seems that Hörmander does not quote Grothendieck in any of his books. Hörmander's main reference in Functional Analysis was Laurent Schwartz' treatise on Distribution Theory as well as Gelfand & Shilov' Generalized Functions.